# Spring RestTemplate getting Converter exception when using ParameterizedTypeReference

Tags: spring, jackson, resttemplate

Have the following code which correctly recieves String data from REST call and deserializes it:

```
String testDocumentJson = this.restTemplate.postForObject(url, data, String.class);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

The server response is:

```
 {
     "content": [{
         "name": 99,
         "id1": 25,
         "id2": 25,
                   ],
        "last": true,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "totalElements": 53,
        "size": 2500,
        "number": 0,
        "first": true,
        "sort": null,
        "numberOfElements": 1
    }
}
```

Also this example works fine if not used with ParameterizedTypeReference i.e

Can someone please help as to how to resolve this.

Comment: Can you please post your TestResponse model and also your TestDoc model? And also the plain test response you receive from the server.

Comment: EDIT: Just saw it is JSON...

The problem is, that the format you want to deserialize it into does not fit to the response you get.

Comment: @jdickel can we use some custom converters to achieve this?

Comment: Jackson should be able to manage this. Can you post the plain response from the server as well pls?

Comment: Have added the info..Also some comments about how it behaves without ParameterizedTypeReference.thanks

Comment: The content in the response Bad no object closing Tag. A „}“ is missing